# Redirect to Route not working in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2, google-oauth

I'm using Zend Framework 2.2.4 for my app, I added a 'Sign-in with Google' option for the login page. But it's not redirecting on the exact page, it goes back to the login page and places a #

**e.g.
    myapp.dev/login#**

This is the method for the 'Sign-in with Google', this is located at my `LoggingController.php`

```php
public function loginSocialsAction()
{
    $googleClient = $this->getGoogleClient();

    $code = $this->params()->fromQuery('code', '');

    $googleOauthV2 = new \Google_Oauth2Service($googleClient);

    #if successful validation from Google
    if (isset($code)) {
        $googleClient->authenticate($code);

        $gdata = $googleOauthV2->userinfo->get();
        $user = $this->getUsersTable()->getByEmail($gdata['email']);
    }

    if ($googleClient->getAccessToken() && isset($gdata['email'])) {

        if (!empty($user)) {
            $user->role = $this->getRoleTable()->get($user->roleId);

            $session = new Session\Container('currentuser');
            $session->user = $user;

            $this->initializeSession($session);
            // if success, go to records page
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('records');

        } else {
            $message = 'The user is not in the system.';
            $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('error')->addErrorMessage($message);
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
        }

    } else {
        $message = 'Google auth failed.';
        $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('error')->addErrorMessage($message);
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
    }
}
```

Please mention the things that I missed or you want to know. Any idea(s) would really help!

Comment: Please provide your routes (`login`and `records`), the error can be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for redirection.

***For Controller Redirection***

```
return $this->redirect()->toUrl($this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl().'/any/path/here/'.<<ID HERE, IF YOU WANT>>);
```

***For View Redirection***

In this case, a button **Cancel** when clicked redirects, resetting the values.

```
<button type="reset"   
   <a  href="<?php echo $this->basePath('your/path/here/'. <<ID HERE IF ANY>> ) ?>">Cancel
         </a>
</button>
```

The obvious difference can be seen, since **controller's** URLs are redirected using `getBaseUrl()` while **view's** URLs are redirected using `basepath()`.